# Getting non-adaptive icons from installed apps on Android

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which gets a list of all the apps currently installed on your phone and I'm trying to get the app's square icon. If I do the following:

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(thePackageName);
```

which gets the icon but it's displayed depending on the style currently set on the device (round, squicle, etc). If I change the icon shape on the phone it gets the icon with the new shape applied. Is there any way of getting just the square icon?

I've also been trying to use `getDrawableForDensity()` which you can use with the icon density and the theme which I thought could be what I was after but I still couldn't get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution although it might not be the best way to do it. I couldn't get the icon as a whole without the Adaptive mask so I've checked if the Drawable is an AdaptiveIconDrawable then I extract both the background & foreground and paint them both to the canvas to be returned.

```
    public Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        } else if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
                && (drawable instanceof AdaptiveIconDrawable)) {
            AdaptiveIconDrawable icon = ((AdaptiveIconDrawable)drawable);
            Drawable bg = icon.getBackground();
            Drawable fg = icon.getForeground();
            int w = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int h = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
            icon.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
            bg.draw(canvas);
            if (fg instanceof Drawable) {
                fg.draw(canvas);
            }
            return result;
        }
        float density = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int defaultWidth = (int)(48* density);
        int defaultHeight = (int)(48* density);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(defaultWidth, defaultHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
```